# XPathSelectElement select the second when there is more than one

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Hi Not sure if this can be done but I know someone here will know :)

using

```
XElement oNodeEquip = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ItemAry/Item/Equip");
```

how would I select Equip from the second  in the following:

```
<TestInfo>
  <ItemAry>
    <Item>
      <testData>ABC</testData>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <testData>XYZ</testData>
      <Equip>xxx</Equip>
    </Item>
  </ItemAry>
</TestInfo>
```

there will always be at lease 2 `<Item>` and the node I want the value from will always be in the second `<Item>`

this is a WPF app using .Net 4.0

Comment: Wouldn't a more suitable example have an `<Equip>` element in the first `<Item>` element, as well?

Comment: Hi O R Mapper, thanks but in the real XML Equip only ever appears in the second item never in the first so wanted to keep the example the same.

Comment: Only ever in the second item? i.e. Never in the first, and never in the third or later items? If so, doesn't your XPath expression already work?

Comment: Ok sorry not giving the full story, currently it is in the first Item, soon it will be in both the first and second for cut over period and then only in the second. thus I want to deploy this during the phase it is in both and not have to make any further changes. thanks for your help and interest your solution seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XPath expression:

```
//ItemAry/Item[2]/Equip
```

It considers only the second `<Item>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with Linq to Xml:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var second = (string)xdoc.Descendants("Item").Skip(1).Element("Equip");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer and will keep it in mind, but just need a quick fix to existing code using xpath.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
(/*/ItemAry/Item)[2]/Equip
```

**The currently selected answer can produce unexpected results, depending on the specific XML document at hand**:

```
//ItemAry/Item[2]/Equip
```

selects the `Equip` children of *all* `Item` elements that are the second `Item` child of their `ItemAry` parent.

**So, if the source XML document is**:

```
<TestInfo>
  <ItemAry>
    <Item>
      <testData>ABC</testData>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <testData>XYZ</testData>
      <Equip>xxx</Equip>
    </Item>
  </ItemAry>
  <ItemAry>
    <Item>
      <testData>DEF</testData>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <testData>TUW</testData>
      <Equip>yyy</Equip>
    </Item>
  </ItemAry>
</TestInfo>
```

**the above potentially-wrong expression selects *two* elements**:

```
<Equip>xxx</Equip>
<Equip>yyy</Equip>
```

**The correct expression provided in this answer**:

```
(/*/ItemAry/Item)[2]/Equip
```

selects just:

```
<Equip>xxx</Equip>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ceratin about position of the node, you can use [`position()` function](http://oreilly.com/catalog/xmlnut/chapter/ch09.html) in your `XPath`:

```
XElement oNodeEquip = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ItemAry/Item[position()=2]/Equip");
```