# Selecting element based on other element values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have referred [XPathSelectElement select the second when there is more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581556/xpathselectelement-select-the-second-when-there-is-more-than-one) and [XPath and XPathSelectElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289784/xpath-and-xpathselectelement). But this is a different question.

I have following xml. I need to find out the Message element value  (from StatusDetail) corresponding to Sequence 2. If there is no sequence 2 present, it should return null. What is the best way to do this in C# using `XPathSelectElement`?

Note: There can be any number of StatusDetail (or not at all)

Note:  The StatusDetail element can be in any order. We need to look only for the value “2” in  2

**CODE**

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"  
          <Status>
            <StatusMsg>
                <StatusType>INVOICE</StatusType>
                <StatusCode>READYPAY</StatusCode>
                <StatusTimestamp>2013-03-19T21:20:54Z</StatusTimestamp>
                <StatusDetail>
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
                <Message>.Document posted successfully </Message>
                </StatusDetail>
                <StatusDetail>
                <Sequence>2 </Sequence>
                <Message>Invoice is ready for pay</Message>
                </StatusDetail>
            </StatusMsg>
            </Status>
           ");

 var statusDetails = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail");
```

**UPDATE**

Following is the solution that I am using based on the selected answer

```
var statusDetails = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail/Sequence[text()=2]/../Message").FirstOrDefault();
if (statusDetails != null)
{
     selectedMessage = statusDetails.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var statusDetails = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail/Sequence[text()=2]/../Message");
```

It uses `text()` to select element by its value and parent selector `/..` to get back from that element to its parent.

Add `ToList()` or `SingleOrDefault` to enumerate results and save it into a list or single `XElement` object.

*Update*

LINQ to XML query version:

```
var results = from sd in xDoc.Root.Elements("StatusMsg").Elements("StatusDetail")
              let s = sd.Element("Sequence")
              where s != null && ((string)s).Trim() == "2"
              select (string)sd.Element("Message");
```

and with Method-based query:

```
results = xDoc.Root.Elements("StatusMsg").Elements("StatusDetail")
              .Select(sd => new { sd, s = sd.Element("Sequence") })
              .Where(x => x.s != null && ((string)x.s).Trim() == "2")
              .Select(x => (string)x.sd.Element("Message"))
```

You can add another `.Where(x => x != null)` to skip `null` results (which exists when there is `StatusDetail` with `Seqience == 2`, but no `Message` element.

Comment: I've tested it and it works. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: I don't understand you. How do you try applying `Root` into `XPathSelectElements`? Add `ToList()` to enumerate the query and get results as `List<XElement>`

Comment: Following is what I am using. It works fine. var statusDetails = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(@"Status/StatusMsg/StatusDetail/Sequence[text()=2]/../Message").FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Why not using LINQ to XML:

```
var result = xDoc.Descendants("StatusDetail")
            .Where(x =>
                       {
                           var xElement = x.Element("Sequence");
                           return xElement != null && xElement.Value.Trim() == "2";
                       })
            .Select(x => (string)x.Element("Message"))
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: If we encounter a `StatusDetail` element (with value 2) without a `Message` element, it will fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `(string)x.Element` to avoid `(?:)` consitional statement. However, I think `XPath` is more readable in that case.

Comment: It fails if there is a `StatusDetail` element without `Sequence`

Comment: Need to use FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault, as there can be multiple elements with same sequence